# How to show the convergence of the series $\sum\frac{\sqrt{(x+n^2)^2 + y^2}}{(x-n^2)^2+y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For fixed $x,y \in \mathbb R$, how to show the convergence of the series $\sum_n\frac{\sqrt{(x+n^2)^2 + y^2}}{(x-n^2)^2+y^2}$, for $x,y$ such that $ (x-n^2)^2+y^2 \neq 0$

My thought is its behavior will be similar to $\frac{1}{n^2}$ , for $x\leqslant 0$, I am thinking about using that $(x-n^2)^2 + y^2 \geqslant n^4$, but I do not know how to deal with the numerator. Also I do not know how to deal with $x<0$.

Comment: Sum over what? Over every $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb Z^2\setminus\{(n^2,0)\}$, for some fixed $n$?

Comment: Your have the right basic idea. Try fixing $x,y$ and then multiplying top and bottom by $1/n^4.$

Comment: Can you be more specific?@zhw.

Comment: @Keith *Can you*? At least address the first comment...

Comment: I have edited the question. It is the sum over $n$ for some fixed $x,y$.@DonAntonio

Comment: You may separate the terms of your series according to $n^2\leq 2|x|$ or $n^2>2|x|$. Then it is not diffucult to provide upper bounds for such components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$ \sum_{n: n^2\leq 2|x|}\!\!\frac{\sqrt{(x+n^2)^2+y^2}}{(x-n^2)^2+y^2}\leq\frac{1}{y^2}\!\!\sum_{n:n^2\leq 2|x|}\sqrt{9x^2+y^2}\leq\frac{\sqrt{2|x|+1}}{y^2}\sqrt{9x^2+y^2}$$
and
$$ \sum_{n:n^2>2|x|}\!\!\frac{\sqrt{(x+n^2)^2+y^2}}{(x-n^2)^2+y^2}\leq \sum_{n\geq \sqrt{2|x|}}\frac{4(n^2+|x|+|y|)}{n^4}$$
is clearly convergent.

Comment: $(x-n^2)^2 + y^2 = x^2 -2n^2x+n^4+y^2 \leqslant x^2-2n^2x+n^4$. Are u trying to make $x^2 -2n^2x \geqslant 0$?

Comment: In which part? I am simply separating the contributes given by small and large values of $n$. In the first part I am exploiting the fact that the sum associated with small $n$s has a finite number of terms, in the second part I am exploiting the fact that the terms associated with large $n$s decay pretty fast to zero.

Comment: Yes, but about the second part I am a little confused about why $(x-n^2)^2+y^2 \geqslant n^4$, can you explain further?

Comment: @Keith: we are assuming $|x|<\frac{n^2}{2}$, hence $(x-n^2)^2$ is larger than $\frac{n^4}{4}$ (that is the origin of the $4$ appearing in the numerator)

Comment: I see, thanks a lot.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? If I would want uniform convergence on any compact subset $\{(x,y)| \in \mathbb R^2 \mathbb - Z \}$, then the first estimation would not work since it has a $y^2$ on the denominator, right?

Comment: @Keith: also, if $y=0$ the series has a closed form depending on the $\coth$ function.

Comment: Can I argue that if I viewed it as a continuous function then it would be bounded on a compact subset.